# Synchronization failed in objective C

Tags: objective-c, sup

While I was running my program in objective C using  SUP 2.1.3 as back end. My exception is

```
** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'SUPPersistenceException', reason: 'SUPPersistenceException from synchronize: -- SUPSynchronizeException: Sync failed: -857 (ERROR) %1:[-10244] The MobiLink server has encountered an error and the s'
```

Why this exception is happening?

Comment: I don't get your question. Make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you Post your Code which is executed during connect ?

From My Point of view, you have lost connectivity during Sync

Comment: You are correct Tim Fiedler.Thank you very much for your response.I am a beginner in this native application.We lost the connectivity in between.thats why